# Tensorflow-GPU will not run GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a model on ubuntu 18 and I followed the documentation of Tesorflow-GPU :
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu
ubuntu 18
CUDA 11
tensorflow-gpu 1.13
And I'm getting this problem :

```
2021-02-03 13:16:00.755944: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcudart.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-02-03 13:16:00.756245: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcublas.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-02-03 13:16:00.756534: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcufft.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcufft.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-02-03 13:16:00.756834: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcurand.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcurand.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-02-03 13:16:00.757106: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcusolver.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-02-03 13:16:00.757389: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcusparse.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-02-03 13:16:00.757674: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcudnn.so.7'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-02-03 13:16:00.757800: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1663] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Skipping registering GPU devices...
2021-02-03 13:16:00.757899: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-02-03 13:16:00.757992: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0 
2021-02-03 13:16:00.758088: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N 
2021-02-03 13:16:01.201726: W tensorflow/compiler/jit/mark_for_compilation_pass.cc:1412] (One-time warning): Not using XLA:CPU for cluster because envvar TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit was not set.  If you want XLA:CPU, either set that envvar, or use experimental_jit_scope to enable XLA:CPU.  To confirm that XLA is active, pass --vmodule=xla_compilation_cache=1 (as a proper command-line flag, not via TF_XLA_FLAGS) or set the envvar XLA_FLAGS=--xla_hlo_profile.
```

from the error I can see that the CUDA files are not found and after checking there is not such files.

Comment: I think you need to xtracted files to the CUDA installation folder https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-gpu-in-ubuntu-20-04-4ee3ca4cb75d

Comment: This version of TensorFlow requires CUDA 10, not any other version, you need to install exactly this version.

Comment: The problem was solved check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Tensorflow version 1.13 ,I have updated it for 2.4 and it have worked.